# Hard drive not showing up after windows 10 upgrade

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd

I have two hard drives, the first drive is a ssd which I have installed my OS (windows 10) on. The second is a normal HDD which I use for storage and booting up ubuntu. When I had windows 8.1 I could access it just fine, but when I upgraded to windows 10 it just "disappeared" and I could no longer find it/access it. However, when I boot up ubuntu I can access it again.

Here is the picture of my disk management setup.
[image: disk management setup screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like Windows is unable to determine the filesystem of your 700GB partition

It could be the case, that your missing partition is formatted with the Ext2 or Ext4 file system.

If you want to test if this is the case, try downloading and running [Ext2Explorer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) and see if that allows you to read the disk volume you're missing. The Ext2 Explorer is a standalone application and does not require you to install anything. So it's ideal for testing if this is your issue.

If that works, I would recommend you install the [Ext2Fsd driver](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) in Windows for permanent Ext filesystem support.

For more detailed instructions and information about the tools described here, you could take a look at [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/).

Comment: Hi, when I installed ext2Explorer I could browse the HDD. I installed the driver and restarted my computer, but the drive still does not appear when i open "This pc"/My computer. What could be the problem?

Comment: Does the drive appear his time in Windows Disk Management and with what status? If it's online you might need to just assign a drive letter to it.